# Using CSS flexible box model, can you "float" one item to the left while centering a second?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

We want to use the CSS flexible box model, but need to "float" one item to the left while centering the second.

Here's what we would like to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7GQ/

We would like to use the flexible box model so we can easily center the items vertically while achieving this horizontal layout.

Of course, we could use relative positioning to manually place everything, but we're wondering if there is a natural way of achieving this look with the flexible box model.

We need to support Mobile Safari only.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Horizontal center is best achieved by using `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` and a set `width`. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7GQ/1/

Vertical center is harder and has been addressed [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=vertical%20align%20css%20site%3astackoverflow.com) times.

[html5please](http://html5please.com) recommends [avoiding](http://html5please.com/#flexbox) using the flexible box model and it is **not** supported on mobile devices.